# Why are processes blocked when open FIFO

Tags: c, linux

I write a test for FIFO. Server writes string "hello" to the client through FIFO. But it seems that the two processes are blocked.I think the FIFO are opened for writing and reading by server and client. But the two processes output nothing.

```
/* FIFO test */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys.stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define FIFOPATH  "/home/hel/fifo" // define file path 

int client(void);
int server(void);

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;

    /* create FIFO */
    if (mkfifo(FIFOPATH, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR) < 0) {
        if (errno == EEXIST) { // already exists, ok 
        }

        /* error */
        else {
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    /* create process */
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) { // error, process exits.
        exit(-1);
    } else if (pid == 0) { // child, server
          server();

          return 0; // exit
    }

    /* parent, client */
    client();

    return 0;
}       

/* server */
int server(void)
{
    int ret;
    int fd;

    /* open fifo for writing */
    if ((fd = open(FIFOPATH, 0200)) < 0) {
        printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1; // error
    }

    ret = write(fd, "hello", 5);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}

/* client */
int client(void)
{
    char recvBuf[100];
    int fd;
    int ret;

    /* open fifo for reading */
    if ((fd = open(FIFOPATH, 0400)) < 0) {
        printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));
        return -1; // error
    }

    ret = read(fd, recvBuf, 5);
    printf("ret: %d %d\n", ret, fd);
    printf("client receive %s\n", recvBuf);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two problems. The first one is the main problem.

1. The `flags` parameters passed to `open` are incorrect. They are not supposed to be unix file permission flags as it appears you have provided. The server should use `O_WRONLY` and the client should use `O_RDONLY`.
2. `write(fd, "hello", 5);` and `read(fd, recvBuf, 5);` are not writing and reading the terminating NUL character of the string. But then it is printed as a string: `printf("client receive %s\n", recvBuf);`. This invokes Undefined Behaviour (even though there is a good chance the program may appear to "work"). Change `5` to `6`.

Answer (score 0):

open() uses following flags:-

```
       O_RDONLY        open for reading only
       O_WRONLY        open for writing only
       O_RDWR          open for reading and writing
       O_NONBLOCK      do not block on open or for data to become available
       O_APPEND        append on each write
       O_CREAT         create file if it does not exist
       O_TRUNC         truncate size to 0
       O_EXCL          error if O_CREAT and the file exists
       O_SHLOCK        atomically obtain a shared lock
       O_EXLOCK        atomically obtain an exclusive lock
       O_NOFOLLOW      do not follow symlinks
       O_SYMLINK       allow open of symlinks
       O_EVTONLY       descriptor requested for event notifications only
       O_CLOEXEC       mark as close-on-exec
```

for FIFO you must use O_RDONLY in client and O_WRONLY in server in your program.

0200 and 0400 permissions are not working for open(). you can check the the flag value in  as

*#define    O_RDONLY    0x0000      /* open for reading only */

*#define    O_WRONLY    0x0001      /* open for writing only */

thats why open blocks in your case as it doesn't get correct flag.